# How to create a scatter plot that will link points that are from a same category on mouse hover?

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I want to create a scatter plot that will link points that share a particular attribute when hovered over and also display a tooltip, similar to the example here https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAWem.gif

I am currently using ggvis to make the plot, although I'm not sure it supports this functionality. The visualization will be displayed in shiny.This is what my code to make the visualization looks like at the moment. The categorical variable that I want the points to be joined by is `Choice_2`.

```
plot_data %>%
ggvis(x= ~X,y= ~Y,  size= ~Size_val,stroke := "white") %>%
layer_points(fill= ~Choice_1, opacity := I(2/5)) %>%
scale_numeric(property = 'size', domain = c(0.01,0.52),range = c(100,5200))%>%
hide_legend(scales = 'size') %>%
bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")
```

Any help or references would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you played around with key :=... I have found that useful for the inclusion of data from sources which are not in the plot

Comment: I have used it with regards to including extra information in tool tips that was not used to display the plot. I've been able to draw the lines and the points separately, but have not been able to add any interactivity that operates simultaneously on points and the related lines

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @vck look into `Rcharts`. Note that the example is taken from [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/472)

```
library(rCharts)
r1<- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type="scatterChart")
r1$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e,graph){
return '<b>carb</b>: ' + e.point.carb
} !#")
r1$chart(size = '#! function(d){return d.disp} !#')
r1
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
require(devtools)
install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')
library(rCharts)

x=rnorm(100)
y=rnorm(100)
data<-data.frame(y,x)
rPlot(y~x, data = data, type = "point")
```

[rCharts](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/) is a useful package that you can use polycharts and highcharts with R.